# How do I get this CheckLine function to work properly?

Tags: python

```
currentLine = ''
ipAddresses = ''
def openFiles():
    #RETRIEVE wireShark.txt for reading
    currentLine = open("wireShark.txt").read().splitlines()
    print("File wireShark.txt was opened.")
    ipAddresses = open("IPAddress.txt")
    print("File IPAddress.txt was opened.")
    return currentLine
    return ipAddresses

def CheckLine(currentLine):
    ipAddresses.write("Source" + "\t\t" + "Destination\n")
    for line in currentLine:
        obj = line.split(' ')
        if 'Source' in obj and 'Destination' in obj:
            temp = currentLine.readline.split()
            ipAddresses.write(temp[2] + "\t" + temp[3] + "\n")
openFiles()
CheckLine(currentLine)
```

> I keep getting this error:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "extractIP.py", line 30, in 
> CheckLine(currentLine)
> File "extractIP.py", line 22, in CheckLine
> ipAddresses.write("Source" + "\t\t" + "Destination\n")
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: Can you share some text from the files? I know it is not related to the error, but I need them to run the code properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be that you are not familiar with the concepts of returning values and variables.

First, when you access `currentLine` or `ipAddresses` in the function `openFiles`, you are accessing a *local* variable, instead of the *global* (i.e. shared between all functions.) Therefore, after `openFiles()`, `ipAddresses` is still `''`, causing Python to fail to write to an empty string. If you meant to access the *global* variable, you should add

```
global currentLine
global ipAddresses
```

to both functions. However, global variables are usually not recommended as they can be accessed (and modified) by too many functions. Instead you can do this

```
def openFiles():
    #RETRIEVE wireShark.txt for reading
    currentLine = open("wireShark.txt").read().splitlines()
    print("File wireShark.txt was opened.")
    ipAddresses = open("IPAddress.txt")
    print("File IPAddress.txt was opened.")
    return currentLine, ipAddresses

currentLine, ipAddresses = openFiles()
```

Second, you cannot return two values by writing two consecutive `return` statements. After the first statement, the execution would already be returned, so the second one would never be reached. See above for the fix.

Last, when you open a file for writing, you must explicitly set the file mode `w` (or `w+`, etc, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open) for all options). So something like this:

```
ipAddresses = open("IPAddress.txt", "w")
```

Comment: Perfect! This got me on the right track. Thank you for the explanation! I'm still new to this.